# MyAppState is not displaying anything

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:qrscan/qrscan.dart' as scanner;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Uint8List bytes = Uint8List(0);
  TextEditingController _inputController;
  TextEditingController _outputController;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    this._inputController = new TextEditingController();
    this._outputController = new TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(

        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],

        body: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                _qrCodeWidget(this.bytes, context),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        controller: this._inputController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                        onSubmitted: (value) => _generateBarCode(value),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.text_fields),
                          helperText: 'Please input your code to generage qrcode image.',
                          hintText: 'Please Input Your Code',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 7, vertical: 15),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      TextField(
                        controller: this._outputController,
                        maxLines: 2,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.wrap_text),
                          helperText: 'The barcode or qrcode you scan will be displayed in this area.',
                          hintText: 'The barcode or qrcode you scan will be displayed in this area.',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 7, vertical: 15),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      this._buttonGroup(),
                      SizedBox(height: 70),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => _scanBytes(),
          tooltip: 'Take a Photo',
          child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _qrCodeWidget(Uint8List bytes, BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 6,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.verified_user, size: 18, color: Colors.green),
                  Text('  Generate Qrcode', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(Icons.more_vert, size: 18, color: Colors.black54),
                ],
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 9),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black12,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(4), topRight: Radius.circular(4)),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 40, right: 40, top: 30, bottom: 10),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 190,
                    child: bytes.isEmpty
                        ? Center(
                      child: Text('Empty code ... ',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
                    )
                        : Image.memory(bytes),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, left: 25, right: 25),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 5,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            child: Text(
                              'remove',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15, color: Colors.blue),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
                            onTap: () =>
                                this.setState(() => this.bytes = Uint8List(0)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text('|', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors
                            .black26)),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 5,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {
                              final success = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
                                  this.bytes);
                              SnackBar snackBar;
                              if (success) {
                                snackBar = new SnackBar(content: new Text(
                                    'Successful Preservation!'));
                                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                              } else {
                                snackBar =
                                new SnackBar(content: new Text('Save failed!'));
                              }
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'save',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15, color: Colors.blue),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black26),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buttonGroup() {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 120,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => _generateBarCode(this._inputController.text),
              child: Card(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Image.asset('images/generate_qrcode.png'),
                    ),
                    Divider(height: 20),
                    Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("Generate")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 120,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: _scan,
              child: Card(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Image.asset('images/scanner.png'),
                    ),
                    Divider(height: 20),
                    Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("Scan")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 120,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: _scanPhoto,
              child: Card(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Image.asset('images/albums.png'),
                    ),
                    Divider(height: 20),
                    Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("Scan Photo")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future _scan() async {
    String barcode = await scanner.scan();
    if (barcode == null) {
      print('nothing return.');
    } else {
      this._outputController.text = barcode;
    }
  }

  Future _scanPhoto() async {
    String barcode = await scanner.scanPhoto();
    this._outputController.text = barcode;
  }

  Future _scanPath(String path) async {
    String barcode = await scanner.scanPath(path);
    this._outputController.text = barcode;
  }

  Future _scanBytes() async {
    File file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    Uint8List bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
    String barcode = await scanner.scanBytes(bytes);
    this._outputController.text = barcode;
  }

  Future _generateBarCode(String inputCode) async {
    Uint8List result = await scanner.generateBarCode(inputCode);
    this.setState(() => this.bytes = result);
  }
}
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _sPrefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  List<String> listOne, listTwo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listOne = [];
    listTwo = [];
  }

  Future<Null> addString() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _sPrefs;
    listOne.add(controller.text);
    prefs.setStringList('list', listOne);
    setState(() {
      controller.text = '';
    });
  }

  Future<Null> clearItems() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _sPrefs;
    prefs.clear();
    setState(() {
      listOne = [];
      listTwo = [];
    });
  }

  Future<Null> getStrings() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _sPrefs;
    listTwo = prefs.getStringList('list');
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<Null> updateStrings(String str) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _sPrefs;
    setState(() {
      listOne.remove(str);
      listTwo.remove(str);
    });
    prefs.setStringList('list', listOne);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getStrings();
    return Center(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
              controller: controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Type in something...',
              )),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Submit"),
            onPressed: () {
              addString();
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Clear"),
            onPressed: () {
              clearItems();
            },
          ),
          Flex(
            direction: Axis.vertical,
            children: listTwo == null
                ? []
                : listTwo
                .map((String s) => Dismissible(
                key: Key(s),
                onDismissed: (direction) {
                  updateStrings(s);
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(s),
                )))
                .toList(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here the first Appstate creates a Qr code reader. Second is for creating an input controller with shared preferences that can store and retrieve data locally. But when running the code the app displays only the qrscan part and 2nd is not working. I'm new to `Flutter`. I've just started working on Android Studio. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call Another class from **home** property of the MyApp class.
As you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcpx1.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
   runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    //Here I have called MyWidget Class 
   home: MyWidget()
  );
 }
}

 class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
 }

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
 Uint8List bytes = Uint8List(0);
 TextEditingController _inputController;
 TextEditingController _outputController;
 @override
  initState() {
   super.initState();
   this._inputController = new TextEditingController();
   this._outputController = new TextEditingController();
}

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     home: Scaffold(
```

Comment: Can You Share me the code Sir. I don't get it correctly

Comment: I have edited my answer with the code. Kindly check it out